# Unable to retrieve the value of textbox inside repeater, when repeater is bound to datatable at postback

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, data-binding, datatable, postback

I have a repeater that is bound to datatable but the last column of the repeater has a textbox (not programmatically created). I have a button but outside repeater. In button_click event i wanted to get the value entered in the textbox as well as the data in that row of the repeater. In/during postback, the datatable is again recreated and bounded to the repeater, but in the button_click event the textbox is empty (assuming that the user entered a value and click the button). I have done the rebinding which i get most of the answer when googling it. Im not sure if the databinding of the datatable to the repeater affects the textbox column since that column is not part of the datatable? How do i go about it? Please see HTML and behind the code below,

**HTML**

```
<div id="ucprodres-any-mfg">
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptAnyMfg" runat="server" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div id="ucprodres-any-mfg-row">
                    <div class="ucprodres-stock manufacturer">
                        <div class="ucprodres-mfg ">
                            <div id="ucprodres-exp-any-mfg" data-swap="-">+</div>
                            <div>&nbsp;&nbsp;<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Mfg")%></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ucprodres-stock qty-avail">
                        <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Qty")%>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ucprodres-stock availability">
                        <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Availability")%>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ucprodres-stock unit-price">
                        <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "QtyRange")%>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ucprodres-stock dollar">
                        <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "QtyRangePrice")%>
                    </div>
                    <div id="txtboxID" class="ucprodres-stock qty-required" >
                        <asp:TextBox ID="tbxAnyMfg" runat="server" style="text-align: right"
                            ToolTip="Quantity should not be more than available quantity."></asp:TextBox>
                        <div class="ucprodres-txtbox-info">Quantity should not be more than available quantity</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
```

**BEHIND CODE**

```
Public Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button.Click
For Each rptitems As RepeaterItem In rptAnyMfg.Items
        If (rptitems.ItemType = ListItemType.Item) Or (rptitems.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem) Then
            Dim tbxQtyReqd As TextBox = rptitems.FindControl("tbxAnyMfg")
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbxQtyReqd.Text) Then
                If tbxQtyReqd.Text > "0" Then
                    Dim mfg As String = rptitems.DataItem("Mfg").ToString
                    Dim qty As String = rptitems.DataItem("Qty").ToString
                    Dim avail As String = rptitems.DataItem("Availability").ToString
                    Dim qtyrange As String = rptitems.DataItem("QtyRange").ToString
                    Dim unitprice As String = rptitems.DataItem("QtyRangePrice").ToString
                    Dim qtyreqd As String = tbxQtyReqd.Text
                    Dim rfqpart As New Parts.InStock
                    Dim rfqpartdetails As New Parts.InStock.PartsData(mfg, qty, avail, qtyrange, unitprice, qtyreqd)
                    rfqpart.Add(rfqpartdetails)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very good at VB syntax so I put the sample in C# and you can convert it to VB yourself.

first of all you need to make sure that you Bind your Repeater control once on a page postback so make sure that you have this code on your Page_load method:

> ```
>     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         if (!IsPostBack)
>            BindRepeater();
>     }
>
>
>     void BindRepeater()
>     {
>         rptAnyMfg.DataSource = GetDataFromDB();
>         rptAnyMfg.DataBind();
>     }
> ```

then you on your Button_Click event check the the textbox control before unboxing to the textbox control like below:

> ```
>     protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptAnyMfg.Items)
>         {
>             if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
>             {
>                 if ((TextBox)item.FindControl("tbxAnyMfg") != null && 
>                     !string.IsNullOrEmpty(((TextBox)item.FindControl("tbxAnyMfg")).Text))
>                 {
>                     int value;
>                     string text = ((TextBox)item.FindControl("tbxAnyMfg")).Text;
>
>                     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) && int.TryParse(text, out value))
>                     {
>                         if (value > 0)
>                         {
>                             // your value assignments here
>                         }
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

just to improve your code it's good if you check the textbox value is integer before you compare it in if statement.

let me know if you are having trouble to use this code.

Comment: i did rebind my repeater, actually on every postback because i dont check if the page is postback or not because i need to recreate the datatable that is being used. In button_click event i was able to find the textbox but the problem is, that it is empty. Do you have any idea as to why it is empty?

Answer (score 0):

Well what i can say, the textboxes values are always there all along on postback. it is my program logic that made me unable to see it. though this is not im pretty sure the best solution to my problem but anyway, it worked.
First, what i did was to capture the value of the textboxes (with the use of array list) on postback (only) in Page_load event.

```
Private Sub GetTextBoxValue()
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each rptitem As RepeaterItem In rptAnyMfg.Items
        Dim txtbox As TextBox = rptitem.FindControl("tbxAnyMfg")
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbox.Text) Then
            arrQtyReqd.Add(txtbox.Text)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Second, make the textbox's column part of the datatable meaning i created a column in my datatable for the textboxes values. Since my program will recreate the datatable (even on postback), during this stage, I update this column with the value from the arraylist (i used to store the textbox's value, remember the Sub GetTextBoxValue). I've learned that there's no way that i can use a common function or event that i will be able to get the value from a textbox and at the same time a dataitem value.

Third, on button_click event i used the datatable instead to get the all the values i needed (with change in textbox) rather the repeater.

Well that's it folks, i hope someday this will help someone too.